# Difference between event EventHandler<T> vs EventHandler<T>

Tags: events, .net-3.5, syntax, event-handling

What is the difference between these 2 statements?

```
private static event EventHandler<MyEventArg> MyNewEvent;
private static EventHandler<MyEventArg> MyNewEvent;
```

They both seem to behave the same. I am using .net 3.5.  Are there any other ways to define this so that they are functionally identical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you can invoke event only from class where it was declared.

Event is like automatic property. For every event compiler creates:

1. Underlying private delegate.
2. `add` public method.
3. `remove` public method.

When other class does `+=` it is converted to call to `add`. Since delegate is private it can't be called from other class, and it is impossible to get/change invocation list freely.